# Efficient averaging by indices in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing

I want to avoid using a loop to create a list of average values from a larger vector.  I have the indices in the larger vector for each location in the 'average' vector, but I don't want to wrap this in a loop.  Is there a cellfun() method in Matlab to expedite the process.  Code and examples follow:

```
tVector = 10 : 15;
values  = [ 10.1 10.2 10.3 11.4 11.5 11.6 11.7 12.8 12.9 13 13.1 13.2 13.3 13.3 14 14.1 14.2 ];
[ x, n ] = histc( values, tVector );
if any( x ~= 0 )
    indxList = unique( n );
    avgList = NaN * ones( length( indxList ), 1 );
    for k = 1 : length( indxList )
        theseIndxs = find( indxList( k ) == n );
        avgValue = mean( values( theseIndxs ) );
        avgList( indxList( k ) ) = avgValue;
    end
end
```

The data here are for a trivial example with a small data set.  But, my data have much longer lengths, so I'd like to avoid the 'for' loop with possibly the cellfun().

Answer (score 1):

Use [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with the `@mean` function:

```
avgList = accumarray(n(:), values(:), [], @mean);
```

Comment: There is a failure point in using this function with n as given by histc.   Take a set of doubles which are separated by a constant interval, say 5.  Then take diff( x ), which ought to be 5.  But with machine error, you can have diff( x ) = 5 + 1E-5 (or so), such that there are non-constant bin population.  The accumarray function in this example returns averaged values for diff( x ) = 5 but a zero value for diff( x ) = 5 + 1E-5, leaving you with the need to first find the eps and construct the bin vector with 5 + 1E-5 (or whatever).  Caveat emptor.  Can send data set to prove.

Comment: @BenjaminLevy That's a problem with how you create `n`

Comment: Correct.  Just pointing out machine error.  Commonly mislaid.